# How can I use Magento 2.4.3 Rest API to add tracking information to existing shipments?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.4

How to add the tracking info to an existing shipment in magento 2.4.3 using Rest Api?

We have created the shipment for orders via Rest Api, but some of the shipment created without adding the tracking information in magento 2.4.3p1.